# Facebook registration plugin alternative for google-plus users?

Tags: facebook, google-plus

Is there a google-plus api I can use to do the same thing as the facebook registration plugin does?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.